# LabVIEW - mobile applications

Tags: mobile, frameworks, labview

As far as I am concerned and what I've already implemented there is a way to cooperate somehow with mobile apps such as sending some instructions between mobile and LabVIEW instruments but...

***Is there any way to implement mobile application with LabVIEW ?***

I suppose that officially not, but what about some external frameworks such as LabVIEW hacker toolkit ?

Comment: You could try asking http://www.tsxperts.com/ if they have plans to develop a LabVIEW compiler for Android or iOS, along the lines of their Arduino compiler and forthcoming Raspberry Pi compiler. The Arduino compiler is limited to a subset of LabVIEW functions but it does work. I imagine implementing this for mobile platforms would be more involved, but not impossible.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen anything that allows you to create native apps. The usual solutions other than data dashboard are using web technologies:

1. Write a html page that LabVIEW can host that can load on the mobile device and use http or websockets for communications. There are some toolkits to automate this for example LabSocket (though not sure how much mobile testing is done with it).
2. Remote viewing technologies. I saw one the other day called wezarp which works on mobile.

All of these depending on a Windows based application that you are talking too though. I'm afraid natively I don't think anything exists and would be very hard to implement as you would need to play with the LabVIEW compiler to cross-compile to objective-c, java or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There was a way: [**NI LabVIEW mobile module**](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/12222) which worked for windows mobile. You would program an app in LabVIEW, compile it and load onto your Windows phone. I recollect it worked pretty stable. The solution is not recommended for new projects

For dashboard style panels, there is  [**Data Dashboard for LabVIEW**](http://www.ni.com/newsletter/51387/en/) Android smartphone version allows you to view only. (tablet version allows you to exercise limited control options) Also available for [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-dashboard-for-labview/id481303987?mt=8).

Something available [here](https://www.ni.com/mobile/) for select devices only

Comment: Thank you for your response, I guess that in case of windows mobile, after compiling the app to .exe it is not a problem to open it on mobile phone. I am mostly interested in IOS and Android. Also I am familiar with data dashboard for LabVIEW, which works quite well on IOS and a bit worse on Android :)